# Sql two table combination and distinct only specific values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables

```
products
--------
product_id
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

```
product_to_group
----------------
product_id | product_group_id
1            10
2            10
3            10
4            20
5            20
```

```
SELECT p.product_id, p2g.product_group_id 
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN product_to_group p2g ON (p.product_id = p2g.product_id)
```

The result is

```
product_id | product_group_id
1            10
2            10
3            10
4            20
5            20
6            NULL
7            NULL
8            NULL
```

The problem is here, I want to
-select all rows which product_group_id value is NULL.
-select one of row which product_group_id column has same value.
-product_id not important. It can be any of them in itself.

I want this result

```
product id | product_group_id
1            10
4            20
6            NULL
7            NULL
8            NULL
```

I have been working on it for hours and I did not get the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION`:

```
SELECT MIN(p.product_id), pg.product_group_id
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN product_to_group AS pg ON p.product_id = pg.product_id
WHERE pg.product_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY pg.product_group_id

UNION ALL

SELECT p.product_id, pg.product_group_id
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN product_to_group AS pg ON p.product_id = pg.product_id
WHERE pg.product_id IS NULL
```

The first part of the `UNION` uses grouping in order to return unique `product_group_id` values, whereas the second part returns all `product` records not being related to a `product_to_group` record.

Answer (score 1):

Most SQL engines spport ANSI standard window functions.  You can use `row_number()` for this:

```
SELECT product_id, product_group_id
FROM (SELECT p.product_id, p2g.product_group_id,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p2g.product_group_id ORDER BY p2g.product_group_id) as seqnum
       FROM products p LEFT JOIN
            product_to_group p2g
            ON p.product_id = p2g.product_id
     ) pg
WHERE product_group_id IS NULL or seqnum = 1
```

Comment: i have tried in mysql and but i got this error, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY p2g.product_group_id ORDER BY p2g.product_group_id) as seqnum, problem is solved and thanks for your answer

Comment: @theMasculist . . . The question was not tagged mysql when I answered it.